# looping through an object using a for in

Tags: javascript, for-in-loop

Can anyone help me?be stuck for a while, all i need to do is print out the properties of my object,anyone know why this doesnt work?

```
<!DOCTYPE   html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function person(name, dateOfBirth, nationality){
        this.name = name;
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
        this.nationality = nationality;
    }

     var mark = new person("mark oshea",25,"irish");
    var text = ""; 
    for(x in mark) {
       text += mark[x];
    }


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: mark[x] should just be x.

Comment: Do you mean printing the values of the properties or the name of the properties?

Comment: @Sebas I interpreted the question as the names of the properties.

Comment: what do you mean "doesn't work"

Comment: an alternative solution to the problem is `text = Object.keys(mark).join(' ')`, side-stepping your issue

Comment: Where is the `text` variable defined? You need to define it and set it to an empty string for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

A `for ... in` loop will loop through all properties of a given array / object. 
You try to access your object with the property (which you actually want).

In your case `text += x;` should be what you're looking for if you want the properties.

If you want to get the values of your object you can use `forEach` for example like:

```
mark.forEach( function(value){
    text += value; 
});
```

Comment: False. `for x in foo` will put the KEYS of foo into x, not the values.

Comment: YOu'd be building a string containing `name dateofBirth national`, not `mark oshea 25 irish`

Comment: @MarcB "print out the properties" I assumed that meant the names of the properties not the values. The asker should clarify

Comment: yes, but you said "loop through all the values, ... not the key".  that's completely backwards

Answer (score 0):

Your html is missing closing/opening elements, and you were not declaring the 'var text'.
Try it like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE   html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Person</h1>
<p id="person"></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function person(name, dateOfBirth, nationality){
      this.name = name;
      this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
      this.nationality = nationality;
  }

  var text = "";
  var mark = new person("mark oshea",25,"irish");
  for(x in mark) {
     text += mark[x] + " ";
  }

  var person_paragraph = document.getElementById("person");
  person_paragraph.innerHTML = text;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

For more info on DOM functions, I'd recommend fiddling through [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model).

Comment: Yes i did mean values my apologies.Thanks all, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your text variable is trapped in the scope of your for loop.  Adding this line outside of the for loop solves it, as demonstrated in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/7z0qonb3/

```
var text = '';
```